# How to implement the onselect event on htmx?

Tags: django, htmx

I'm a django developer and I'm new to htmx.
I was wondering if there was an easy way to implement the onselect event in htmx.

I have the following dropdown:

[image: Change user role on select]

When the role is selected "onselect", I want to send an http request to the back-end using htmx(not jquery or javascript)

How can I do this?

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks!

Tried searching "onselect" on [htmx docs](https://htmx.org/docs) but there's no built in implementation.
Tried searching "onselect htmx" stack overflow but I couldn't find a helpful post.

Answer (score 1):

#### I found the answer upon re-reading the docs.

#### I found the solution with `[hx-trigger]` on the `change` event [hx-trigger](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/)

```
    <select
      class="custom-select"
      id="role"
      name="role"
      hx-post="{% url 'set_user_role' user.id  %}"
      hx-trigger="change">
      <option value=""></option>
      {% for role in roles %}
       <option value="{{role.id}}" 
           {% if role == current_role %}selected{% endif %}
       >{{role.name}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `hx-trigger="changed"`.

https://htmx.org/docs/#triggers

If you don't specify trigger attr then the request will trigger on selection change anyways. Please check out the following example:

https://htmx.org/examples/value-select/

Comment: Hi mario, thanks for the reply. I've solved the problem and yes it's using `hx-trigger` but it should be `hx-trigger="change"` not "changed"


**"Please pay attention change is the name of the event and changed is the name of the modifier." - https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-trigger/**